# In Azure databricks writing pyspark dataframe to eventhub is taking too long as there3 Million records in dataframe

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

Oracle database table has 3 million records. I need to read it into dataframe and then convert it to json format and send it to eventhub for downstream systems.

Below is my pyspark code to connect and read oracle db table as dataframe

```
df = spark.read \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", databaseurl) \
            .option("query","select * from tablename") \
            .option("user", loginusername) \
            .option("password", password) \
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
            .option("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false") \
            .load()
```

then I am converting the column names and values of each row into json  (placing under a new column named body) and then sending it to Eventhub.

I have defined ehconf and eventhub connection string. Below is my write to eventhub code

```
df.select("body") \
   .write\
   .format("eventhubs") \
   .options(**ehconf) \    
   .save()
```

my pyspark code is taking 8 hours to send 3 million records to eventhub.

Could you please suggest how to write pyspark dataframe to eventhub faster ?

My Eventhub is created under eventhub cluster which has 1 CU in capacity

**Databricks cluster config** :
mode: Standard
runtime: 10.3
worker type: Standard_D16as_v4  64GB Memory,16 cores  (min workers :1, max workers:5)
driver type: Standard_D16as_v4  64GB Memory,16 cores

Comment: Partitionizing your JDBC query might help. Check this out https://youtu.be/vD3k-moYgmU?t=1146

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the jdbc connector just uses one connection to the database by default so most of your workers are probably idle. That is something you can confirm in Cluster Settings > Metrics > Ganglia UI.

To actually make use of all the workers the jdbc connector needs to know how to parallelize retrieving your data. For this you need a field that has evenly distributed data over its values. For example if you have a date field in your data and every date has a similar amount of records, you can use it to split up the data:

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
  .option("dbtable", tableName) \
  .option("user", jdbcUsername) \
  .option("password", jdbcPassword) \
  .option("numPartitions", 64) \
  .option("partitionColumn", "<dateField>") \
  .option("lowerBound", "2019-01-01") \
  .option("upperBound", "2022-04-07") \
  .load()
```

You have to define the field name and the min and max value of that field so that the jdbc connector can try to split the work evenly between the workers. The `numPartitions` is the amount of individual connections opened and the best value depends on the count of workers in your cluster and how many connections your datasource can handle.