# How to split pyspark dataframe with 3 million records equally in azure databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have a pyspark dataframe which connect to oracle database and read a table which has 3 million records. I need to write this dataframe to azure eventhub.

Below is the sample pyspark datframe write to eventhub code.

```
df.select("body") \
   .write\
   .format("eventhubs") \
   .options(**ehconf) \    
   .save()
```

How to split my pyspark dataframe into 10 parts equally (300k records/ dataframe) ?

So that I can send iterate each of these 10 pyspark dataframes to eventhub.

Comment: maybe use the feature: .partitionBy("partition_column_name"), and this new column "partition_column_name" can be assigned with value 1, 2, ..., 10, corresponding to roughly equally number of rows?

Comment: Don't duplicate your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791689/in-azure-databricks-writing-pyspark-dataframe-to-eventhub-is-taking-too-long-as.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Azure databricks writing pyspark dataframe to eventhub is taking too long as there3 Million records in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791689/in-azure-databricks-writing-pyspark-dataframe-to-eventhub-is-taking-too-long-as)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of partitions by

`df.select('body').coalesce(10).write`

OR

`df.select('body').repartition(10).write`

> coalesce only decrease the number of partitions while repartition can
> increase or decrease.  repartition will do full shuffle, while
> coalesce(2) will keep partition 1 & 2 as it is and move anything in
> other partitions to fit into partition 1 & 2.

So, if your current partitions are higher than 10, use `coalesce`.
(You can check the num of partitions by `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`)